# Mysql select result as a text variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have this two variables getting a SQL longtext column (`$results_text`) and another (`$results_f2`) getting information from the user :

Thats my new code:

```
    <?php
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT rc.text2, rl.* FROM table_config AS rc JOIN table_list AS rl ON rc.user = rl.user WHERE rl.email = 'user@gmail.com'");
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
      $text2 = $row1[0];
      $name = $row1[3];
      $role = $row1[4];
      $company = $row1[6];

      echo $text2 .= str_replace(":name:", $name, $text2);
      echo $text2 .= str_replace(":role:", $role, $text2);
      echo $text2 .= str_replace(":company:", $company, $text2);
    }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

It's Working but is giving me a lot of scrap like one text2 with name, another with role, another with company, then finaly one with all the variables/strings replaced.

Comment: What do you mean by: _append inside $row1['text1']_. What does `$row1['text1']` look like?

Comment: Hey @RobMoll I've updated the code and you can see more information in the comments bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop will only work during the first iteration of the outer loop. Once you've finished fetching the results from a query, it doesn't go back to the beginning the next time.

Since the second query just returns one row, you should just fetch it once, outside of the loop.

Or you can simply join the two tables in one query.

```
$results = mysqli_query($conn, "
    SELECT tc.text1, tl.*
    FROM table_config AS tc
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM table_list AS tl
        WHERE tl.user = 'user'
        LIMIT 1) AS tl
    WHERE tc.user = 'user'");
```

You're getting 3 outputs because you're echoing each replacement. You should do all the replacements and then echo.

```
      $text2 .= str_replace(":name:", $name, $text2);
      $text2 .= str_replace(":role:", $role, $text2);
      $text2 .= str_replace(":company:", $company, $text2);
      echo $text2;
```

You can also do all the replacements at once by putting the templates and replacements into arrays.

```
$text2 = str_replace([":name:", ":role:", ":company:"], [$name, $role, $company], $text2);
echo $text2;
```

Comment: btw - That query works on mysql sql editor but on php shows // mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in// meaning theres no rows as result,

Comment: That's worked but the same result like 2 texts with 1 string each.

$results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT tc1.text1, tl2.* FROM table_config AS tc1 LEFT JOIN table_list AS tl2 ON tc1.user = tl2.user WHERE tl2.email = 'email'");

while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) 
{
  $rpld = array (str_replace(":name:", $row1[3], $row1[0]), str_replace(":role:", $row1[4], $row1[0]));
  print_r($rpld);

Comment: I've even tried to put <?php echo $row1[3]; ?> inside the text1 on table_config but no success.

Comment: I forgot the `$conn` argument to `mysqli_query`.

Comment: I've changed it to join with a subquery that only returns one row from `table_list`. But when you use `LIMIT`, you should generally use `ORDER BY` so you get a predictable row out of all the matches.

Comment: That's not the problem. I got only one "row" putting email in where statement. The problem is the "columns", because I need to show column "name", "role" and "company" inside the text on column "text1", but when the "while" condition pass thought the "rows", it show me "text1" with "name", then "text1" again with "role", then "text1"again with "company". Maybe the problem is the "while" condition, so I need to pass thought  the array just one time and get all the strings/columns..

Comment: Please update the question to show sample data and the desired result.

Comment: I don't see any data.

Comment: **Hey @Barmar you can see the result at:**
[https://surebotapp.com/wf_test.php] 

**So in table config I have the column text1, with this text:** 
_(Hi :name:, you are reading this text because you are :role: and I posted a question in :company:.)_
**In the table list I have tha name, role and company.**
**After many crap, the last line is correct with all information.**

Comment: This is the correct link: [surebotapp.com/wf_test.php](http://surebotapp.com/wf_test.php)

Comment: I don't want to see the results. Show sample database contents, and what the desired result is from those contents.

Comment: column 'name' = Barmar
column 'text'= Hi :name:, you are reading this text because you are :role: and I posted a question in :company:.
column 'role' = Programmer
column 'company' = stackoverflow

Comment: The problem is that you're echoing 3 times. Perform the 3 substitutions, then echo the final result.

Comment: Can you show me how to perform the 3 substitutions without an array please or how to avoid repeat the array results in one echo?
Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. 
That's worked.
$text2 = str_replace([":name:", ":role:", ":company:"], [$name, $role, $company], $text2);
echo $text2;